# Hiding php extension for static files

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have used this rule in categories:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ categories.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ categories.php?url=$1
```

I want to hide php extension already for static files like xxx.php. Im using this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php  -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

This rule not working and xxx.php goes to categories.php page. What rule may I use for static pages? may I use any "folder/(.*)$ $1.php" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should work fine, *if* you make sure to put the second set of rules *first*. Remember, the rules are executed in order. So, in the order you have the rules in your post, a request to `xxx` will be rewritten as `categories.php?url=xxx` before the second rule ever sees the request... so it never triggers.